# Count keywords in SEC Edgar 10-K filings text-body with Python

Tags: python, parsing, edgar

I am trying to parse the text section of the SEC Edgar texts in Python 3, e.g.: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000796343-14-000004.txt

My goal is to collect the number of occurrences in the visible text body of the 10-K statements of certain keywords and save them to a dictionary (i.e., I am not interested in any tables, exhibits, etc.).

I am very new to Python and would appreciate any help!

This is what I have written so far, but here the code doesn't return the right number of occurrences and it does not capture the main text body visible to the end user.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# this part I would like to change such that it only collects words visible to the normal user in the page (is that the body?) 

def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and the_word in text)
    print(words)
    print('*'*20)
    return len(words)


def main():
    url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/0000796343-14-000004.txt'
    word_list = ['assets']
    for word in word_list:
        count = count_words(url, word)
        print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} occurrences of word: {}'.format(url, count, word))
        print('--'*20)

# this part I dont understand 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For the example case, what is the correct number of occurrences? What occurrences does your code find that it shouldn't? Or not find that it should?

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for looking into this! I tried with the word "digital" and it returns 382 matches when you just open the link and use the search function in the browser. However, when I open the end user-friendly view (here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/796343/000079634314000004/adbe10kfy13.htm), I only get 176 returns, which is the number I am interested in. Also, there are some parts in the .txt link that I am not sure if they are translated properly - they look weird as the code only covers approx. a third of the page and only consists of special characters

Comment: If, in your sample code, you change 'assets' to 'digital', the output says "contains 493 occurrences of word: digital", but 493 is neither 382 nor 176. So your code isn't counting occurrences. Instead, because you're using 'soup.find', it only finds the first element-text that satisfies your lambda, and the variable 'words' holds that text as a string, and len(words) just returns the length of that string. (I.e., it contains 493 characters.) You need to use `soup.find_all`. (However, this doesn't answer the question you actually asked, so I'm leaving it as a comment.)